# Swift Specialize Generic Class for Void

Tags: generics, swift2

Lets say I have a class like:

```
class Function<T> {
    var ptr: () -> T

    init<Func>(block: Func, args: AnyObject...) {
        self.ptr = {() -> T in
            return callFunction(unsafeBitCast(block, AnyObject.self), args) as! T
        }
    }
}

postfix operator ^ { }
postfix func ^ <T>(left: Function<T>) -> T {
    return left.ptr()
}
```

Now I want to specialize this class so that if `T` is `Void`, it won't return anything.. How can I do this?

Currently my work around is:

```
class Function<T> {
    var ptr: () -> T

    init<Func>(block: Func, args: AnyObject...) {
        self.ptr = {() -> T in
            if let result = callFunction(unsafeBitCast(block, AnyObject.self), args) as? T {
                return result
            }

            return Void() as! T
        }
    }
}

postfix operator ^ { }
postfix func ^ <T>(left: Function<T>) -> T {
    return left.ptr()
}
```

Is there really no other way?